# Dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu on a hybrid drive via LiveUSB

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, system-installation

I have been meaning to dual boot Ubuntu 13.10/12.04 (or Linux Mint 16) along side my Windows 8.1. I have a Lenovo U410 with a hybrid drive (30 gb SSD for cache, 750 HDD). I found it really difficult to do so. My BIOS has something called UEFI mode (dunno really what that is) and while reading around, I understood that might cause some problems to a certain extent.

Things I have tried:

1. Boot via flash drive created with pendrivelinux
2. Made an ext4 partition on my HDD
3. Start the installer
4. Ubuntu did not see any other OS installed
5. Was able to install it only on my SSD after I created a partition table on it.

I thought to myself that probably installing on the SSD should be fine, especially since I do not need more than 30GBs since I want to use it especially for scripting/developing.

Unfortunately, after I have done so, Ubuntu booted, but my windows refused to boot at all. It was probably given the fact that the cache was 'corrupt' with Ubuntu.

I then tried to install Ubuntu via wubi. It booted up okay, I can now dual boot. However, my windows performance drastically reduced since I installed Ubuntu via wubi. This happened to me in the past on some other laptop, but after I managed to partition it properly, everything was back to normal.

Any thoughts on how I should go about this? I really want Ubuntu since I find developing in it so much smoother than in windows.

Comment: try :http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported hope this'll help

Comment: Trying it right now. I will come back with answers. Thanks !

Comment: The guide seems not to cover my problem. I do not have the problem with the secure boot when I run the powershell. But Ubuntu still doesn't want to detect both of my hard drives, nor does it detect there is another OS installed

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read the following two pages:

- [My Web page on installing Linux on EFI-based computers](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)
- [The Ubuntu community documentation on EFI installations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Keep in mind that your disk probably appears to be a single disk to any OS, including both Linux and Windows, so you shouldn't need to do anything special with it -- at least, not compared to other EFI installations. (EFI normally uses the GUID Partition Table [GPT] rather than the older Master Boot Record [MBR] partitioning system.)

Your claim that you installed Ubuntu via WUBI is suspect. The last I heard, WUBI did not work with EFI-based Windows installations, which essentially all Windows 8 and 8.1 pre-installs are. Furthermore, WUBI is on the way out, so using it on a new installation is inadvisable because it may become difficult to support such installations in the near future. Overall, I suspect that you installed in some other way and for some reason you think it was WUBI, but it wasn't.

If you need more advice, I recommend you run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/), post the `RESULTS.txt` file that it produces to [a pastebin site,](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL for your document here. That will give us a better idea of your current configuration.